# Como puedo mostrar en un formulario una fecha que viene de la base de datos con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al momento de mostrar los datos en un modal para actualizar los datos, no puedo mostrar la fecha de nacimiento.

```
    fetch(`${url}pacientes/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);

            document.getElementById('nombres').value = data.nombre;
            document.getElementById('apellidos').value = data.apellidos;
            document.getElementById('edad').value = data.edad;
            document.getElementById('genero').value = data.genero;
            document.getElementById('direccion').value = data.direccion;
            document.getElementById('lugarDeNacimiento').value = data.lugarNacimiento;
            document.getElementById('fechaDeNacimiento').value = data.fechaNacimiento
            
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

Esta es la respuesta de la consulta a MongoDB

```
{
     nombre:"Génesis Nohemy", 
     apellidos:"Arevalo Carranza", 
     edad:35, genero:"Femenino", 
     direccion:"XXXXXX", 
     lugarNacimiento:"XXXXX", 
     fechaNacimiento:"2004-10-22T00:00:00.000Z" 
}
```

Este es el formulario html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="dateOfBirth">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaDeNacimiento" class="input form-control" id="fechaNacimiento" placeholder="Agregar Fecha de Nacimiento" />
          </div>
```

Comment: Que significa "no puedo mostrar"? hay algún error, aparece vacío..

Comment: No hay error, solo que no se como capturar la respuesta y mostrarla.

Comment: Si, es por el formato, ahí dejo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `.value` de la fecha de un input tipo "date" es siempre con el formato "aaaa-mm-dd" [fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), entonces puedes hacer esto:

```js
const fecha = new Date("2004-10-22T00:00:00.000Z"); // <-- respuesta de la base de datos 

document.getElementById('fechaDeNacimiento').value = fecha.getFullYear() + "-"+ (fecha.getMonth()+1) + "-" + fecha.getDate();
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fechaDeNacimiento" class="input form-control" id="fechaNacimiento" placeholder="Agregar Fecha de Nacimiento" />
```

En tu caso sería `const fecha = new Date(data.fechaNacimiento)`.

También funcionaría `fecha.toISOString().substring(0, 10)`.

En este caso particular también funcionaría `data.fechaNacimiento.substring(0, 10)`, sin necesidad de convertir a tipo `Date`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me funciono perfecto.